# Graph API only returns one out of several followed Sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph, graph-api

I tried accessing the followed sites for a Sharepoint using an HTTP Request, but it returns only one out of six pages I currently follow.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/followedSites
```

The one that is being shown is a group page while all the others are a few group sites and a few communication sites.

I couldn't find any restriction to the request why some pages might be shown, and others won't.

Any advice or pointers on what could be causing the problem would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you admin in your Microsoft 365 tenant? I guess you are since I get `{"error":{"code":"InvalidAuthenticationToken","message":"Access token is empty."...` in response using MS Edge

Comment: Yes, I'm a Global Admin in this tenant

Comment: I don't get any results (even though I follow 3 sites) running the query in PowerShell `PS C:\> Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Sites
PS C:\> Connect-MgGraph -Scopes 'User.Read.All, Sites.Read.All, Sites.ReadWrite.All'
Welcome To Microsoft Graph!
PS C:\> Get-MgUserFollowedSite -UserId *******************************
PS C:\>` so I'm thinking there could be a service unavailable now?!

Comment: I'm wondering if this might be a bug but I can't find anything about it online. It's been like that for a while already, I'l keep on watching.